# Vuejs form first input value always fails to validate

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, validation

I have a parent and child form. Submit button is on parent, if there are invalid inputs from child, I would like to disable the Submit button. Example zip code must consist of only 5 numbers. 12345c would be invalid, The form takes 12345c but doesnt get it as invalid, however on all next invalid inputs it can detect them, 12345cc, 12345ccc. Also when I delete the invalid characters one by one it continues detecting the invalid arguments but fails to recognize first valid argument, when I delete 1 more character it sees it as valid(although invalid)

In Short: the validation is correct but always 1 step behind after any input change.

Here is my code:

```
updateFieldValue: function (data) {
  this.formData[data.key].value = data.value;
  this.requiredFieldsDone = this.allRequiredFieldsFilled();
  this.formWasUpdated();
  this.$emit('general-form-data-updated')
},
formWasUpdated: function () {
  let result = false;
  for (const [key, formField] of Object.entries(this.formData)) {
    if (formField.value !== formField.initialValue) {
      result = true;
    }
  }
  this.areFieldsValid = this.fullFormValidated();
  console.log('Child valid');
  console.log(this.areFieldsValid);
  
  this.hasChanged = result;
  this.$emit(
      'general-edit-form-has-changed',
      this.hasChanged,
      this.areFieldsValid
  );
},

fullFormValidated: function () {
  let validated = true;
  console.log('validateForm for loop');
  for (let inputElement in this.$refs) {
    let errors = this.$refs[inputElement].validateInput();     
    if (errors) {
      validated = false;
    }
  }
  console.log('validated boolean');
  console.log(validated);
  return validated;
},
validateInput: function() {
  this.form.validateFields(this.validateInputCallback);
  return this.validateErrors;
},
validateInputCallback: function(errors, values ) {
  if ( errors ) {
    this.validateErrors = errors;
  } else {
    this.validateErrors = false;
  }
},
```

Console Output:

```
validateForm for loop
address-edit-form.vue:613 validated boolean
address-edit-form.vue:614 true
address-edit-form.vue:506 Child valid
address-edit-form.vue:507 true
address-edit-modal.vue:124 Parent valid
address-edit-modal.vue:125 true
index.js:120 async-validator: ['field.value value 12345c does not match pattern /^[0-9]{5,5}$/']
```

Im using ant Forms: https://ant.design/components/form

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you provide a link to a reproduction of the issue? It is also important to understand how the "this.form.validateFields" method works, are you using some lib?

Comment: Im using Ant Forms https://ant.design/components/form , reproducing it on web would be difficult. I will try... Our developers suspect false timing, validateInput() is validating values before the change.